# LLVM.sln file was not generated while building clang

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cmake, clang, llvm

I am building clang on a windows machine following the tutorial http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html#build . I am using Visual Studio 2015 instead of 2017 version. The command

> cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -A x64 -Thost=x64 ..\llvm
>   -Thost=x64

does not create LLVM.sln file, which is needed.
The command creates CMakeFiles directory, which contains a log file and CMakeSystem.cmake file.

How can I generate an LLVM.sln file or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is output of your `cmake` invocation? Add it to the question post.

Answer (score 0):

At least, one of the problems is that you have options **after** you specified folder with sources. The last '-Thost=x64' is wrong. Try following:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -A x64 -Thost=x64 ..\llvm
```